# How can I programmatically delete a datasource in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, datasource

[RESOLVED]

I have a C# program which interfaces with ColdFusion by running a CFM file. 
One of the tasks of the CFM file is to create three datasources in ColdFusion. This works well.

The issue I am dealing with is that I have a requirement to use the same methodology in order to delete a datasource. According to Adobe's documentation this function is available, but I cannot find any examples of this on the WWW.

Can anyone here guide me as to how to remove a ColdFusion datasource using code within a CFM file?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Ken.

As pointed out by Alex, I really should have included the ColdFusion version number. Version 11.

The working resolution inspired by Ageax's answer is:

```
<cfscript> 
adminObj = createObject("component","cfide.adminapi.administrator"); 
adminObj.login("#URL.cfpw#"); 

myObj = createObject("component","cfide.adminapi.datasource"); 

myObj.deleteDatasource("#URL.ds#");
</cfscript>
```

I have posed my code here, only because this is the code I actually used and tested.

Comment: *One of the tasks of the CFM file is to create three datasources in ColdFusion.* Just guessing, but I'd assume it's using the Admin API.  For deletion, try the deleteDatasource() method in Datasource.cfc https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/configuring-administering/coldfusion-administrator-api-reference.html

Comment: And just out of curiosity, how are you creating the datasources with ColdFusion? Through calls to the AdminAPI? You may already be at the right answer; just look through what's available from the `datasource` object.

Comment: @Shawn - That sounds familiar ;-)

Comment: @Ageax Stay outta my head! Or type slower, or something. That's what I get for not refreshing the page before adding comments.

Comment: @Shawn - But, but... that's where I get some of my best thoughts!

Comment: `"that's where I get some of my best thoughts"` >> Now you terrify me.

Comment: Heh.. that would be scary. We developers are disturbingly weird bunch ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can programmatically call the [CF Admin API](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/configuring-administering/coldfusion-administrator-api-reference.html). I believe you can do something like this inside a ColdFusion file.

```
<cfscript>
    /* Connect to CF Admin API */
    dbConnection = CreateObject("cfide.adminapi.administrator").login("adminPW","adminUser");
    if (dbConnection) {    
        /* Instantiate datasource object */
        ds = createObject("cfide.adminapi.datasource"); 

        /* Delete the datasource */
        ds.deleteDatasource("myDatasourceName"); 
    }
</cfscript>
```

Note: I don't currently have a CF server that I can test on, so please double-check me.

Comment: Just an extra information, in the CFAdmin `Disable access to internal ColdFusion Java components` should be unchecked for this to work. https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQldB.png